# Tmux status sed output different from cli

Tags: linux, command-line, tmux, sed

I've been looking at this for a while now, but I cannot find a reason. When I run the following in a cli, it works as expected:

```
$ uptime | sed "s/.*average: \(.*\), \(.*\), \(.*\)$/\1 \2 \3/g"
0.65 0.54 0.57
```

Now, when I add it to my tmux.conf, as follows:

```
set -g status-right '#[fg=green,bg=default,bright]#(uptime | sed -e "s/.*load average: \(.*\), \(.*\), \(.*\)$/\1 \2 \3/g") #[fg=red,dim,bg=default]#(uptime | cut -f 4-5 -d " " | cut -f1 -d ",") #[fg=white,bg=default]%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y #[default]'
```

... it displays the entire *uptime* output, like it is disregarding what sed is doing to it. I have no idea why this isn't working as expected. Can anyone point me in the right direction, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escaping is quite difficult in tmux. I had to fight with it quite a bit. Looks like you need to escape both the backslashes "\" and the braces "()". Here's an example of using only last minute load average as the right status.

```
set -g status-right '#(uptime | sed "s/.*load average:\\s\\+\\\([0-9.]\\+\\\),.*/\\1%/")'
```

The rest should be easy. Hope this helps.